# Javascript - trying to add a property in a loop

Tags: javascript, midi

I'm trying to write a midi file by adding notes using a loop.
This works fine when adding the first note from an array of notes:

```
 trk1.smfSeqName('Music')
            .ch(0) // all subsequent messahes will go to channel 0
            .program(0x1) // set channel 0 program to piano
           // .tick(100).note('E5', 127, 75) // clock: 100, MIDI channel: 0, note: E5, velocity: 127, duration: 50 clocks
           .tick(50).note(noteArray.at(0), 127, 100)   // can also use numerical values for the notes
```

but when I try and add multiple notes in for loop I get an error

```
for (i = 0; i < noteArray.length; i++) {
            .tick(50).note(noteArray.at(i), 127, 100)   // can also use numerical values for the notes
        }
```

Comment: well for me there is a syntax error in your code, your line starts with `.tick` but the variable is missing

Comment: you probably want `trk1.tick(50).note(noteArray.at(i), 127, 100)` in the loop, you're missing `trk1`

Comment: I've tried putting trk1 in front but it didn't like that!

Comment: @TCP2000, sharing the error message you get would help

Comment: With the for loop added I get:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' (at index.html:31:17)

Comment: Used jsmidgen.js and the loop works fine:

 for (i = 0; noteArray.length > i; i++) {
                track.addNote(0, noteArray.at(i), 128);
            }